# What is the exact and accurate translation of Vājasaneyi Samhita 3.61

Tags: shiva, rudra

What is the accurate translation of this mantra from the Vājasaneyi Samhita -

**ए॒तत्ते॑ रुद्राव॒सं तेन॑ प॒रो मूज॑व॒तोऽती॑हि। अव॑ततधन्वा॒** **पिना॑कावसः॒ कृत्ति॑वासा॒ऽअहि॑ꣳसन्नः शि॒वोऽती॑हि॥**

~ Vājasaneyi Samhita 3.61

Does **"Kṛttim Vasāna"** actually mean "Wearing hide" ? What is the exact meaning of **Kṛtti**?[image]